# VBA code to get hidden fields

Tags: vba, ms-word

Can anyone help me write a macro code which gets hidden field values from a word 2007 file ?

Answer (score 2):

You can try this :

```
Sub mySub()
Dim f As Variant

For Each f In ActiveDocument.Fields
    f.Select
    If Selection.Font.Hidden = True Then
        MsgBox "Field is hidden"
    End If
Next
End Sub
```